# Developing ASP.NET application for a Linux Server

Tags: asp.net, linux, web-deployment, asp.net-core-1.0

The problem: I have created a beautiful ASP.NET application using the 4.5 .Net Framework, and now my Boss would like me to deploy it on a Linux server. I already have looked into using .NET Core 1.0 (also called .NET 5) which is available on Visual Studio 2015, but my company only has Visual Studio 2013.

The question: Is it possible to deploy an application written in Visual Studio 2013 that targets the 4.5 .Net Framework onto a Linux server? If not, what are my best options; should I consider changing my server-side language to one that works on Linux?

Comment: you can use Visual studio 2015's Community edition ..!! it's free , but not for company,

Comment: also look at http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html